# Why basename don't work here

Tags: find, xargs, exec, basename

Why when I do this (I know, it's stupid) it returns the full path, not only the filename as expected?
`ls -l | awk '{print $9}' | xargs -I% find ./my_dir -type f -name "%" -exec echo $(basename {}) \;`

And, yes, I know, it's stupid but the goal was to cp basename{} to {} (and, in the and, I use a loop `for i in $(ls); do find ./my_dir -type f -name $i -exec cp $i {} \;; done`)

Thanks.

Comment: Because the shell replaces `$(basename {})` with `{}` before `xargs` starts. There's probably a duplicate question somewhere. I know [one on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1720752/432690).

Comment: Never do `for i in $(ls)`. It is [bad practice](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), likely to break, and is harder than the simpler and safer `for i in *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code will fail for any filename that contains a space (e.g `this one.txt`) or on any system where the user name or group name contains spaces (a system joined to Active Directory, for example).

The construct `for i in $(ls)` should [not be used](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). Instead, use a wildcard glob, `for i in *`.

Finally, in direct answer to your question about `$(basename {})`. The `$( ... )` value is not protected from the shell with single-quotes, and so it is evaluated *before* the command is executed.  The result of `$(basename {})` is simply `{}` and therefore,

```
xargs -I% find ./my_dir -type f -name "%" -exec echo $(basename {}) \;
```

is parsed and executed as if you had typed this,

```
xargs -I% find ./my_dir -type f -name % -exec echo {} \;
```

You were probably looking for something like this

```
for i in *
do
    find ./my_dir -type f -name "$i" -exec cp "$i" {} \; -quit
done
```

Don't forget that you should *always* double-quote your `$` variables and expressions when you use them. (To be fair, it wouldn't have helped in this case, but it's something you need to get used to doing.)

Comment: "The $( ... ) value is not quoted, and so it is evaluated before the command is executed." -- it'd be evaluated (and `basename` would run) before `find` starts even with quoting.

Comment: well, yes, with single quotes the shell wouldn't run it but before starting `find`, but even then `find` wouldn't expand it either. Because, well, it's just not something it does by itself, hence the `find -exec sh -c '...' sh {} \;` idiom